# Issues converting text to lower case even after making sure it is a string

Tags: python, string, text, nlp, lowercase

I'm struggling to convert my text to lower case even after making sure it is a string. I'm not sure why it says that it's a "series" object when I clearly converted it to a string and even checked that it was converted to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
corpus = data['text'].str.lower()
```